# Name of this property: all maps from given class of spaces into $X$ are nullhomotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal{C}$ be some class of topological spaces. Is there a standard name for the following property of $X$?

*For every space $C\in \mathcal{C}$ all maps $C\to X$ are nullhomotopic.*

(Of course if $X\in\mathcal{C}$, then this property is just contractibility.)

Comment: As this is an extension of the definition of contractibility (or at least is an extension of a statement equivalent to the definition), it would be reasonable I think to call such a space satisfying the condition for $\mathcal{C}$ a '$\mathcal{C}$-contractible' space or 'contractible with respect to $\mathcal{C}$'.